# GET var from php to use in javascript function

Tags: javascript, php

i want to get a var from a php script and use it in a function .. so if i call the var simply with $.get (and document.write) i got an result but how can i integrate this into a function ?

```
$.get( 'http://www.domain.de/content/entwicklung/verdienst.php', function(verdienst_php) { 
//document.write(verdienst_php);
```

});

```
function sendview () {
var datastring = {uid : uid_clear, verdienst : verdienst_php};
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'http://www.domain.de/content/entwicklung/view_succeed.php',
data: datastring,
});
}
```

only put the function into the $.get part didnt work

if i didnt use $.get and write in datastring like

```
verdienst: 1000
```

it works

any suggestions ?

kind regards Dave

Comment: You can not use document.write after the page load. How do you want to integrate it into the function? What is the value returned from the get going to be used?

Comment: I want people to use proper grammar... Seriously dude, learn to use capitals and punctuation. Makes reading questions so much easier.

Comment: document.write was only for example .. i want to load a var from verdienst.php .. so then i want to put the javascript var verdienst_php into the ajax datastring .. in view_succeed.php this data will be saved into a database .. from php side everything works .. but i didnt know how to put verdienst_php in datastring .. if verdienst_php is outside the $.get part it have lost his data .. inside it have data .. but i cannot put the function inside the $.get part

Comment: Does the call just happen when page loads or should it hapen when the click is fired?

Comment: it should do this wenn page is loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are returning exactly what you want from the server, store it in a variable and reference the variable in the other Ajax call.

```
var verdienst_php;
$.get( 'http://www.domain.de/content/entwicklung/verdienst.php',
    function(response) { 
    verdienst_php = response;
});

function sendview () {
    var datastring = {uid : uid_clear, verdienst : verdienst_php};
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://www.domain.de/content/entwicklung/view_succeed.php',
        data: datastring,
    });
}
```

If you want the GET call to happen when the click happens, than you just need to put the post code inside of the GET success callback.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make an extra ajax call to get php variable, you can do it this way :-

```
function sendview () {
    var datastring = {uid : uid_clear, verdienst : getPHPVar('verdienst_php')};
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://www.domain.de/content/entwicklung/view_succeed.php',
        data: datastring,
    });
}

function getPHPVar(varname){
    var returnValue = null;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'yourphpurl.php',
        async: false,
        type: 'post',
        data:{
            task:'getvar',
            varname: varname
        },
        success: function(response){
            returnValue = response;
        }
    });
    return returnValue;
}
```

and in PHP it will look like:

```
<?php 
if($_POST['task'] == 'getvar'){
    echo $$_POST['varname'];
}
```

Also, I think it's actually not needed cause you are getting php variable using ajax, and again using it in another ajax call. so Why don't you just do it in php ?

Comment: @epascarello Sorry, and thanks for pointing out, updated accordingly!